# Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ma-sauce-launcher":"*'

Tags: angular, npm

While running (on windows) ">ng new angular-app" I encountered the error bellow

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ma-sauce-launcher":"*'
Package install failed, see above.

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Worked : 
npm cache clean --force
try
npm install
if false
delete package-lock.json

Answer (score 0):

I used yarn for installing dependencies and that fixed it for me.

npm install -g yarn  => Install yarn

del /S angular-app  => delete whatever you created earlier

ng new --skip-install angular-app  => run the command but don't install dependencies

cd angular-app

yarn   => let yarn install the dependencies.

Comment: great! using yarn works! In my case, the problem it's a bad internet conection, so yard retry but ANGULAR CLI doesn't. Thanks!